# Loop 2 arrays and compare is there equal values ( Undefined offset)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, compare

I have 2 arrays `$group_permissions` and `$result`  while looping `$result` array, I compare `$group_permissions[$keys]->perm_id` from `$group_permissions` array with `$result[$keys]->id` from `$result`  array. 
but record in `$group_permissions` array are less than records in `$result` array. so there error is occuring while looping

> Message:  Undefined offset: 14

```
$result array
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1025
            [name] => Library Membership
            [permission_code] => library_membership
            [hash_code] => 7f7758029e0b3b7f0154e98779f66082
            [description] => Library Membership
            [parent_id] => 0
            [level] => 1
            [sequence] => 10000
            [is_child] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 514
            [name] => Member Profiles
            [permission_code] => mem_pro
            [hash_code] => f3e3f0150a0172eca3f3279f9d3919d6
            [description] => Member Profiles
            [parent_id] => 0
            [level] => 1
            [sequence] => 10008
            [is_child] => 0
        )
```

`$group_permissions array`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [perm_id] => 1321
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [perm_id] => 1322
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [perm_id] => 1323
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [perm_id] => 1324
        )
```

This is my code.

```
$group_permissions = $this->get_group_permissions($user_id);

        $result = $this->getPermisstions();

        $parent_id = array();

        foreach ($result as $keys => $row)
        {
            $sub_data["id"] = $result[$keys]->id;
            $sub_data["text"] = $result[$keys]->name;
            if ($group_permissions[$keys]->perm_id == $result[$keys]->id) {

                $sub_data["state"] = ['selected' => true, 'disabled' => true];
            }
            array_push($parent_id, $result[$keys]->id);

            $data[] = $sub_data;
        }
```

If there is equal values in 2 arrays I want to add this  `$sub_data["state"] = ['selected' => true, 'disabled' => true];` to the `$sub_data` array.

Comment: Why do you rely on items based on same keys would have or not equal IDs? What is the actual datastructure? Why do you only add a `state` array when there is equality? I would do the latter in a more consistant way guaranteeing there is some `state` array always having certain keys. This all might work on the underlying structure, however, it possibly might not be an efficient way to do it.

Comment: You should provide more information in order to get more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please provide Input Array Data and let us know what needs to be checked/compared. Understanding only text and code is difficult. I am downvoting so you can improve your question. This question might be useful to others in future also.

Comment: @Jigar question updated with input arrays, I want to check whether perm _id is in $reult array if available I want to set  $sub_data["state"] = ['selected' => true, 'disabled' => true];

Answer (score 0):

You comparing both array's value, you can check if `$group_permissions` array has particular key or not by using `array_key_exist` function like below:

```
if (array_key_exists($keys, $group_permissions)) {
    if ($group_permissions[$keys]->perm_id == $result[$keys]->id) {
        $sub_data["state"] = ['selected' => true, 'disabled' => true];
    }
}
```

So your code will only work if you have same key. Hope it helps you.